# flutter web onPressed Button is not working

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

---

here is the code :

```dart
class BmiScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const BmiScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BmiScreen> createState() => _BmiScreenState();
}

class _BmiScreenState extends State<BmiScreen> {
  double result = 0;
  TextEditingController height = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController weight = TextEditingController();
  bool isMetric = true;
  bool isImperial = false;
  late List<bool> isSelected;

  @override
  void initState() {
    isSelected = [isMetric,isImperial];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ToggleButtons(
            isSelected: isSelected,
            onPressed: toggleMeasure,
            children: const [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                child: Text('Metric',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                child: Text('Imperial',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Row(children: [Text('Height ${((isMetric) ? "(cm)" : "(inches)")}')]),
          TextField(
            controller: height,
          ),
          Row(children: [Text('Weight ${((isMetric) ? "(kg)" : "(pounds)")}')]),
          TextField(
            controller: weight,
          ),
          Text('Result : $result'),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: (){
              debugPrint(countBmi(int.parse(height.toString()),int.parse(weight.toString())).toString());
              setState(() {
                result = countBmi(int.parse(height.toString()),int.parse(weight.toString()));
              });
            }, 
            child: const Text('Count')
          )
        ],
      ),
    ); 
  }

  double countBmi(int height, int weight){
    final double heightMeter = height/100;
    return weight/(math.pow(heightMeter, 2));

  }
  

  void toggleMeasure(value){
    if(value==0){
      isMetric = true;
      isImperial = false;
    }else{
      isMetric = false;
      isImperial = true;
    }
    setState(() {
      isSelected = [isMetric, isImperial];
    });
  }
}
```

here is the error :

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following FormatException was thrown while handling a gesture:
TextEditingController#d73aa(TextEditingValue(text: ┤├, selection: TextSelection.invalid, composing:
TextRange(start: -1, end: -1)))
```

it seems like flutter web cannot perform an 'onPressed' but 'onTap' is working on the web, but the problem is ElevatedButton doesnt have 'onTap' 
 
is there any alternative for button or is there any ways to fix it?

Comment: Can you include full widget that will reproduce the same issue?

Comment: Can you update from widget class, like it is missing `countBmi` and others variable.

Comment: i cant include the whole widget stackoverflow said "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`height` and `weight` are `TextEditingController`. To get text from `TextEditingController` you need use `.text`.

```dart
final textFromTextEditingController = TextEditingController.text.toString();
```

And I use `tryParse` because it is possible text will get null. and null cant be parse into int and will throw errors.

```dart
// you can also return from the method instead of providing default value
final _height = int.tryParse(height.text.toString()) ?? 0; 
final _weight = int.tryParse(weight.text.toString()) ?? 1;

 result = countBmi(_height, _weight );
```

More about [`TextEditingController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) and [`int.tryParse`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/int/tryParse.html)

Comment: I also encourage using proper naming, like here instead of `height` for controller use `heightController`